# How can I switch camera by onClick using Google Vision API

Tags: google-vision

Can I change `.setFacing(CameraSource.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT)` by clicking button ? I used it for qr-, barcode scanning and want to change cameras.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found answer for my question. 
I just called `CameraSource.release()`, my `init()` method with `FRONT` param and all other logic
and recall `cameraSource.start(visionCameraView.getHolder());`
and it's worked